# JavaScript input field must equal number hidden in JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, validation

I am getting spammed by bots like crazy in my contact us form. I have tried, random security code, code must match code you see. They got around it. I went back to Google recaptcha, they are getting around it. So my only other thought was to create a input field where they have to answer a question, and the number would be hidden inside the JS script. It the number is correct, they will be able to submit the form, if not, they will not be able to. The problem is, JS is not my strong point. Can someone please help me create a way to have the JS check to see if the input field is equal to 10? Thank you in advance.

```js
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
    function check(input) {
        if (squest !== 10) {
            input.setCustomValidity('Answer is incorrect.');
        } else {
            // input is valid -- reset the error message
            input.setCustomValidity('');
        }
    }
</script>
```

```html
<input name="squest" required="required" type="text" id="squest" oninput="check(this)" />

<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="viewbtn" id="btn" name="submit">
```

Comment: Most bots doesn't use a browser to fill forms, or javascript is not enabled, so you must do validation on server side.

Comment: @Triby so in my php insert do a check to see is squest equals 10, if not do not send to mysql?

Comment: yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`squest` refers to the element with `id="squest"` itself, you should take the `value` from that.

[Non-identity / strict inequality (!==)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Nonidentity)

> The *non-identity* operator returns *true* if the operands are not equal and/or not of the same type.

As you are using [non-identity / strict inequality (!==)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Nonidentity) operator, you should convert the value to number.

Also you can use the passed parameter to take the value from the element:

```
if (Number(input.value) !== 10) {
```

```html
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
  function check(input) {
    if (Number(input.value) !== 10) {
      input.setCustomValidity('Answer is incorrect.');
    } else {
      // input is valid -- reset the error message
      input.setCustomValidity('');
    }
  }
</script>

<form>
  <input name="squest" required="required" type="text" id="squest" oninput="check(this)" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="viewbtn" id="btn" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: This won't work if user clicks on submit without changing squest input.

Comment: @Triby it will force them to put in a correct number. I will also take your advice and work on getting verification in my php. If the squest number is not 10, then I can have it not submit or auto deleted from the database without having to do it manually. Thank you everyone.